# DataContextChanged doesn't fire in code behind, even after PropertyChanged in view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datacontext

I want to set the DataContext of a UserControl to a new value, but I am not being successful at it.

- I have an UserControl whose DataContextChanged event would write something to Console.
- I have an instance of that UserControl in XAML, with DataContext bound to the correct property;
- I have a `RaisePropertyChanged` (from MVVM-Light) with a breakpoint configured to write to Console too.

The fact is: Even if the RaisePropertyChanged fires (as shown by breakpoint), the DataContextChanged handler is not called (as shown either by breakpoint or `Console.WriteLine`)

IMPORTANT: When the UserControl is first loaded, it displays the value correctly (that is, it "gets" the value from ViewModel) and the messagem from DataContextChanged is printed to Console. The problem is that I can't get the DataContextChanged handler to fire when calling PontoCanalZoom *setter*, even if RaisePropertyChanged fires appropriately.

ViewModel:

```
public class AnáliseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public PontoAnáliseViewModel PontoCanalZoom
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pontoCanalZoom == null)
                _pontoCanalZoom = PontosAtivos?.FirstOrDefault();

            return _pontoCanalZoom;
        }
        set
        {
            _pontoCanalZoom = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => PontoCanalZoom);
        }
    }
    private PontoAnáliseViewModel _pontoCanalZoom = null;
}

public ICommand ComandoSelecionarCanalNavegação => new RelayCommand<PontoAnáliseViewModel>(SelecionarCanalNavegação);
private void SelecionarCanalNavegação(PontoAnáliseViewModel ponto)
{
    // This calls the setter _and_ raises PropertyChanged event.
    PontoCanalZoom = ponto;
}
```

Instance of Control (`AreaPlotagemAnáliseEMG`):

```
        <plotagem:AreaPlotagemAnáliseEMG 
            DataContext="{Binding PontoCanalZoom, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Control definition:

```
public partial class AreaPlotagemAnáliseEMG : AreaPlotagemBase
{
    public AreaPlotagemAnáliseEMG()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContextChanged += (a, b) => System.Console.WriteLine("Trocou Data Context!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a mvvm developper but the fact that the setter is called only at the Initialization must be because you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface on your Model to force your View to update at each setter call.

Comment: Where are you changing the DataContext?

Comment: @Safe the ObservableObject signature looks to be a INotifyPropertyChanged  base class

Comment: @Safe the setter _is_ successfully called by a command (I updated the ViewModel code above). But even notifying, DatContextChanged is not fired.

Comment: @MikeT I added the command where I call the setter, see my update. I am not explicitly changing the DataContext, I am updating a property wich is data-bound to the DataContext.

Comment: DataContextChanged only fires when... you change the value of the DataContext property.  You aren't changing it, so it doesn't fire.  And INPC events in the object within the DataContext do NOT trigger DataContextChanged.  You need to 1) watch the DCC event 2) when it fires, cast the NewValue to INPC and add an event handler to PropertyChanged, do the same to OldValue and remove your event handler (with proper null checks on both!).

Comment: @Will If I understand right, when I bind DataContext to a property in viewmodel and then set that property to another value, that "replaces" the DataContext thus firing DataContextChanged. Just to make it clear: ViewModel fires PropertyChanged, then View fires DataContextChanged, all this mediated by the DataBinding. Notice the declaration: `<plotagem:AreaPlotagemAnáliseEMG 
            DataContext="{Binding PontoCanalZoom, Mode=OneWay}"/>`. Here, when I set `PontoCanalZoom` in ViewModel, I would expect `DataContextChanged` event in AreaPlotagemAnáliseEMG, wouldn't I?

Comment: DataContextChanged only fires when the instance within DataContext changes.  It uses referential equivalence, IIRC, to determine if a change was made. So you have to make sure of that first.  Second, you should call InitializeComponent last in the constructor, to make sure the event hasn't already fired.  After this, I'd use Snoop to verify your bindings at runtime and examine the DataContext values.

Comment: @heltonbiker Do other Bindings work on the same View when you change the value in the ViewModel?

Comment: @jannagy02 Yes. I created a datetime-valued string that I set in the same command that sets PontoCanalZoom, and added a TextBlock to the View. The textbox updates. Even the DataContext _proprieties_ update in the view when I change them in ViewModel. The problem is the DataContext itself doesn't change...